# UITextField text overlaps clear button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am adding a textfield to my view like this:

```
UITextField* tf_email = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320-btnImage1.size.width)/2, 170, 175, 35)];
    [tf_email setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [tf_email setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [tf_email setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [tf_email setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [tf_email setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [tf_email setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
    [tf_email setDelegate:self];    
    [tf_email setOpaque:YES];
    tf_email.tag=1;
    tf_email.font = TTSTYLEVAR(font);
    tf_email.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    tf_email.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
    [tf_email setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    tf_email.placeholder = @"your@email.com";
    [self.view addSubview:tf_email];
```

When I enter long text in to this field, the text and the clear button overlaps. Does any one know how to fix this?

Comment: try to use standard font and see result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured what the issue was. In another file, I had a category defined for UITextField. This category, specified the text area to be very close to the left and right border. That was causing the overlap.

Lesson learnt: When defining categories, we should use separate files so that the modifications are easily detectable.

Answer (score 12):

Create a subclass of `UITextField` and override the methods given below,

```
/*< Place holder position >*/
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width - 20.0f;
    return bounds;
}

/*< Text Posiotion >*/
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width - 20.0f;
    return bounds;
}
```

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 3):

@Augustine P A, I think a better approach is to call the super and modify the result like this:

```
-(CGRect) textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect rect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    rect.size.width = rect.size.width - 20.0f;
    return rect;
}

-(CGRect) editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect rect = [super editingRectForBounds:bounds];
    rect.size.width = rect.size.width - 20.0f;
    return rect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the text field, call

`[button bringSubviewToFront:self.view];`

Comment: Which view do I need to bring to the front?

Comment: Please see the App Store app on iPad. It has a search button where the text and clear button do not collide. In that case there would be no need to bring one view on top of the other.