# UItextfield text covers the clear button in the textfield in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

[image]

Hello, I'm working on a UITextField now and as the image above shows, the text covers the clear button and I want to fix that.
In this text field, I added a padding on the left side of the text and the right side of the clear button.

```
class testTextField: UITextField {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func commonInit() {
    let leftPadding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 17, height: 0))
    leftPadding.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.leftView = leftPadding
    self.leftViewMode = .always

    // tried adding padding to the rightView, but it hide the clear button
    // let rightPadding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 0))
    // rightPadding.backgroundColor = .red
    // self.rightView = rightPadding
    // self.rightViewMode = .always
    
    
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    self.borderStyle = .none
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    self.textColor = .black
    self.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
}

override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let originalRect = super.clearButtonRect(forBounds: bounds)
    return originalRect.offsetBy(dx: -22, dy: 0)
}

// also tried changing the width of the textRext, but after I implement the following code, the textfield becomes non-clickable...
// override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
//    self.bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width - 20.0;
//        return bounds;
//    }
// override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
//    self.bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width - 20.0;
//        return bounds;
//    }
}
```

After doing some research(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352256/uitextfield-text-overlaps-clear-button)), as I put some comments in the code, I tried adding padding to rightView and changing the textRect, but none of them worked.

I want to keep the clear button where it is now, but I want some space on the left side of the clear button, something like the image below...

[image]

Comment: Subclass and override: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619589-editingrectforbounds ?

Comment: @Shadowrun sorry to ask this but you mean I subclass my testTextField class?
I thought class testTextField: UITextField is already subclassing and I tried overriding editingRect but di not work..
(sorry I'm too beginner to write Swift and not getting used to yet, so correct me if I didn't correctly subclassing...)

Comment: ah I didn't see that, the problem is you were trying to mutate your bounds, not compute a value for bounds: you don't want to use any assignment here: self.bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width - 20.0;  Just make a new CGRect with the right values and return that.  Also please name your own types with a capital letter like "TestTextField", like Int and String etc

Comment: @Shadowrun
Ahh, now I get what you mean! Thank you so much! Problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shadowrun, I was able to solve the issue I had.

I needed to subclass the UITextField and add editingRect. Then return the CGRect with whatever numbers I want to put. My code is something like this.

```
override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 17, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width - 70, height: bounds.size.height)
}
```